# How can I add motion blur to a pre-rendered (existing) video clip?

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, motion-blur

I have some videos recorded at 48fps (which is to say, I'm not exporting objects modeled in Blender, so general motion blur tutorials I've found don't apply) and want to use the "inbetween" frames to help generate final videos at 24fps with some level of motion blur (as if they had been recorded with a slower shutter)

I've found other people trying to do similar things, but their questions are either so old that the answers are full of dead links (which may not reflect the best way to do it in recent versions of VSE/Nodes--which by the way, I have very very little experience with Blender's effects nodes/Cycles so if those are the solution as I'm guessing they are I'd appreciate a breakdown of the relevant specifics if possible) or have something else going on (like masking) that makes the best approach different from my needs. As far as I can tell, my case is very simple, which I guess makes it a bit unusual? Just want to output a video at half the framerate but with motion blur.

Comment: Honestly, I would not do this in Blender, I would do it in DaVinci Resolve... like almost all of my video editing.

Comment: Likewise. Using da Vinci resolve is the answer

Comment: It's hilarious that I was just about to ask a similar question and this was the first question on the query list. 
I would like to know how to store a series of pngs, an animation, with ALL of their inherent data. So *maybe* later I can add motion blur, glare, or what not. What format would store this data, just in case you wanted to use it later?

Comment: PNGs can't store passes, you would have to store one image sequence per pass. Also PNGs are incredibly slow to read and write. PNG is made primarily for internet display, not for production. These reasons are why EXR multilayer is used in the industry.

Comment: There are many tutorials and guides online that show how to save render passes, with or without EXR Multilayer. Search for those, and post here on BSE if you encounter issues @JBRiley

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK The only motion blur Blender can do is either at render time using the engine's motion blur, or in compositing using the Vector and Z passes generated at render time and the Vector Blur Node in Compositing.

But you can't apply the render engine's motion blur nor generate passes after rendering, and you can't do anything on recorded footage.

Sources:

- [Motion Blur — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/motion_blur.html)
- [Vector (Motion) Blur Node — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/vector_blur.html)
- [Passes — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html#cycles)

If you have a render's Vector and Z passes, all you have to do is pass it in Blender's compositor with this setup:

[image]

But if you don't have these passes, Blender has no way to analyze your frames and "invent" motion blur out of it. Other softwares have tools for that, like DaVinci Resolve, but that's out of topic on this website.

Answer (score 1):

### Video Sequence Editor

*One old school fake if you really want motion blur for existing footage in Blender ... probably you are lucky one if your original footage is 48 fps and you want to result in 24 fps, so you have a chance to control a bit better blur effect.*

[image]

Duplicate the strip a few times, each time with one frame offset on Timeline, blend mode *Alpha Over* ... in this example I used 3 duplications so the *Opacity* 1 has to be divided by 3, so Opacity  0,333 ...

[image]
[image]

Notes:

- For Blender 2.79 there are some addons to speed it up the workflow ... [**MBlur**](https://blenderartists.org/t/video-sequence-editor-news-add-ons/1188770) (works for video not image sequence) or similar function integrated in [**Kinoraw Tools**](https://github.com/kinoraw/kinoraw_tools#eco-tools----warning-cpu-intensive) as *Eco Effect* (works for image sequence when in *MetaStrip*).
- In general this technique mimics reality, where camera catches fast moving object partly contaminated by background.Specific pixel is exposed to light without and with moving object. Fading effect is just a result of different amount of exposure of moving object at specific place in space (more far less time spent at that place). So this technique does the same, you are just limited by existing in between frames to get enough smooth transition. That is why I wrote lucky you if you can use 48 fps and divide result to 24 fps that gives you one frame in-between.
- The same you can do in [compositor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0FSI.jpg) ...
- Or you can [try this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Avj4KgUL6yQ) preblured composite and use high-pass to isolate like a vector of motion and use it as a mask for mix original with pre-blurred version.

---

For artistic strike blur (that is just behind moving object) use **Lighten** blend mode and *Opacity* divided by half of previous layer opacity.

[image]

Comment: @LOLock it seems we edited my post at the same time (and it ruins our both edits) so I deleted your unfinished part. Please I appreciate your input, but it would be nicer if you start it by comment. I saw this technique used at colorful fight video so I can't agree it works only for BW graphics ... about colors. Yes, there're some imperfections (I mentioned), but it can be my wrong interpretation or can be fixed by RGB Curves modifier. Here left with blur / right your original https://imgur.com/mXWNHM2 or here https://imgur.com/16qGzYk

Comment: Should have commented first indeed, sorry about that.

Comment: I've seen this technique mainly used on isolated parts, like a layer on 2d animation or in comp, not the whole final render nor live action footage. When the whole render is already done and is not simple shapes BW, I highly suspect it won't look right "as is" and will require adjusting, maybe the color, or the blur quantity itself, using masks to isolate things in the frame and tweak/remove the blur, ... And on fast camera/object movements might just [not work at all](https://i.imgur.com/3D3spef.png). Not saying it can't be done! Just some caveats to keep in mind.

Comment: @LOLock I found original fight video, but the quality is to low to see effect, so just some [screen](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/9/1/9/919dfb40153ad49fef80ed43b6d32bf60bf15135.jpg) of something else. I edit the blend mode that doesn't shift colours. I think all downsides are already visible, even that the result is not so bad for what it is. The movement is fast enough to see effect from 48 to 24fps. Your example is another extreme and if you have a chance to render regular m-blur and play there would not be probably such drastic difference for viewer.